# How to add a calculation in Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I just want to be Per Amount to Paid Amount and result will be posted in balance automatic

this is my admin.py

@admin.register(StudentPaymentSchedules)

```
class StudentPaymentSchedulesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Fullname','Grade_Level','Payment_Schedule','Amount','Student_Payment_Date','Paid_Amount','Balance','Remarks',)
    ordering = ('pk','Students_Enrollment_Records__Education_Levels')
    search_fields = ('Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname','Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname',)
    list_filter = ('Students_Enrollment_Records__Education_Levels',)
    def Fullname(self, obj):
        return  obj.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users
    def Grade_Level(self, obj):
        return  obj.Students_Enrollment_Records.Education_Levels
    actions = ["export_as_csv"]
    def export_as_csv(self, request, queryset):
        meta = self.model._meta
        field_names = [field.name for field in meta.fields]
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}.csv'.format(meta)
        writer = csv.writer(response)

        writer.writerow(field_names)
        for obj in queryset:
          row = writer.writerow([getattr(obj, field) for field in field_names])
        return response
```

I have this models.py

```
class StudentPaymentSchedules(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records=models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Payment_Schedule =models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    Amount = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Student_Payment_Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    Paid_Amount = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Balance = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Remarks=models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
```

for example if the Amount is 1,950 and the Paid Amount is 1500 if the admin click the Save button it will  cocompute.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pre-save signals to do it.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

def balance_reciever(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    Amount = instance.Amount
    Paid_Amount = instance.Paid_Amount
    Balance = Amount-Paid_Amount
    instance.Balance = Balance

pre_save.connect(balance_reciever, sender=StudentPaymentSchedules)
```

Comment: where should i paste it? under the StudentsPaymentSchedule?

Comment: under the models

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Django Admin save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) but I think you shouldn't create a separate column for a division result. Instead you should use `@property` function in your model class like this:

```
class StudentPaymentSchedules(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records=models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Payment_Schedule =models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    Amount = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Student_Payment_Date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    Paid_Amount = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
    Remarks=models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True

    @property
    def balance(self):
        return self.Amount - self.Paid_Amount
```

And use SQL divide function if you need to get data directly from database.